# UiTextField's Touch Down Event on uitableviewcell doesn't work always

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, storyboard, touch

Ok I'm new on iOS, and I found out something really peculiar. I'm using a UITextField embedded in an UITableViewCell, and I'm trying that when I touch the textfield it shows an UIPopOverController with some options.

I was using the EditingDidBegin Event, it works fine, but when I try to touch twice the same textfield just works the first time, so I have to touch another textfield and touch again the first textfield.

So, I tried to change and to use TouchDown Event but I found that it does not always work correctly I have to touch several times the textfield and sometimes it never works, I don't know why, because when I use the same event in an textfield embedded in an UiView everythig works fine.

I don't know if I have to change something on the UiTableView or on the UITableViewCell, I'm using storyboard with xCode 4.2.

I would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with `EditingDidBegin` do call `resignFirstResponder` on your textfield when you are done.
Now next time you tap the textfield it should work as expected.